# Fill all values above the diagonal of a numpy array with a value

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to fill all values above the diagonal of a `numpy` array with a value such as 0.

E.g.

Given:

```
[[ 1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11 12]
 [13 14 15 16]]
```

Output (setting all values above main diagonal to 0):

```
[[ 1  0  0  0]
 [ 5  6  0  0]
 [ 9 10 11  0]
 [13 14 15 16]]
```

I could traverse the needed array elements using loops, but I was looking for a more efficient approach.

Comment: Have a look at [```np.tril```](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tril.html)

Answer (score 0):

Given a `numpy.array` defined as follows:

```
a = numpy.array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
                 [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
                 [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
                 [13, 14, 15, 16]])
```

You can loop over the relevant indices and set them to `0` as follows:

```
for i in range(a.shape[1]):
    for j in range(min(i, a.shape[0])):
        a[j, i] = 0
```

Comment: @L. Grazinger, thank you for this.  I was looking for an approach which acts on all desired array elements in a single command, rather than traversing each element using loops.  I edited my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Per [@Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14923227/kevin)'s comment to my question above, `np.trill` works nicely:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
              [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
              [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
              [13, 14, 15, 16]])
np.tril(a)
```

gives

```
array([[ 1,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 5,  6,  0,  0],
       [ 9, 10, 11,  0],
       [13, 14, 15, 16]])
```